# How to delete a file within the parent directory of the batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

Okay, I apologize that I am very new at this, but I am trying to make my batch file delete a certain item in it's parent directory. This is how my folders are arranged:

- File.zip
- Folder 1

  - delete.bat

My goal is to make "delete.bat" delete "file.zip". So here's my code:

```
rd /s /q %~dp0..\File.zip
```

This seems like it would work but it keeps giving me an error saying "The directory name is invalid". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `rd` is for removing directories, `File.zip` is presumably a file.  Use `del` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm so stupid.